# slim 4 - multiple file upload empty $_FILES array

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I'm havong some trouble to upload multiple file at once in my vue and php app. I'm using slim to have an endpoint where upload request is posted:
On the server side I have this code to test if all works fine:

```
$app->post('/compress', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    var_dump($files); // this will result in empty
    
    //return $response;
});
```

In my javascript code, inside a vue method I have this code that is called when the file input will change:

```
      let formData = new FormData();
      for(let i; i < this.$refs.selectedImages.files.length; i++){
        formData.append('images[]', this.$refs.selectedImages.files[i]);
      }

      let config = {
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        withCredentials: true
      }

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/compress', formData, config)
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response, response.data);
      });
```

tha result is that the `var_dump` will give me empty. How I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debug I've fixed the code. The problem was with the `for()` loop that seems not working to iterate FileList in my case. I've replaced it with a `forEach()` and voilà! The server started to get the uploaded files.

```
let files = this.$resf.selectedImages.files;
let formData = new FormData();
files.forEach( (el) => {
  formData.append('images[]', el); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try this one?**

```
for( var i = 0; i < this.$refs.selectedImages.files.length; i++ ){
    let file = this.$refs.selectedImages.files[i];
    formData.append('images[' + i + ']', file);
}
```

Comment: Tested, but on the server side I get `Undefined index images` that is the name that I have assigned to the `FormData` append field. It's like the `$request->getUploadedFiles()` will not be filled.

Comment: I've also looped like suggested here the `getUploadedFiles()` in the server side code

Comment: uhm try to comment out this one first `$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();` then try to dump the $_FILES

Comment: dump the $_FILES global will result in empty. But slim handle the $_FILES using the $request object :(